# В чем заключается ошибка в алгоритме работы программы и как ее исправить?

Tags: python

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Ввод:**

```py
print_long_words('Как и в прочих заданиях этого урока, в вашем решении функция должна быть определена, но не должна вызываться.')
```

**вывод:**

```
заданиях
 
решении

определена

вызываться
```

вот мой код:

```py
def print_long_words(s):
    [print(i.lower()) for i in s.replace('.', '').replace(',', '').replace(';', '').replace('!', '').replace('?', '').replace(':', '').split()if sum(i.count(j)for j in'аоэиуыеёюяaeiouy') > 3]
```

не работает при таких входных данных:

**Ввод**

```py
print_long_words("""whatever.wherever1solution;solut1onal""")
```

**Ожидаемый результат**

```py
solution
```

**Вывод**

```py
whateverwherever1solutionsolut1onal
```

**UPDATE:**

**Номер теста**

9

**Ввод**

`print_long_words('Как и в прочих заданиях этого урока, в вашем решении функция должна быть определена, но не должна вызываться.'.swapcase())`

**Ожидаемый результат**

```
заданиях
решении
определена
вызываться
```

Comment: в задании сказано не реплейсить знаки препинания, а сплитовать по ним

Comment: @Jack_oS т.е. просто заменить все реплейсы на сплит и правильно заработает?

Comment: нет )) но это первый шаг к пониманию алгоритма

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import re

text = 'Как и в прочих заданиях этого урока, в вашем решении функция должна быть определена, но не должна вызываться.'

rus = 'аоэиуыеёюя'
eng = 'aeiouy'

def print_long_words(data):
    for word in re.split('\s+|\.|;|,|!|1|2|3|4|5|6|7|8|9|0', data):
        word = word.lower()

        if sum([l in rus for l in word]) >= 4:
            print(word)
        if sum([l in eng for l in word]) >= 4:
            print(word)
       
print_long_words(text)
```

Comment: при первом же тесте ошибка(выдает 3 слово с запятой на конце(см. входные данные первого теста и вывод в вопросе)), т.е. так :  _определена,_

Comment: @Андр щас поправлю

Comment: все равно та же ошибка

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч re.split("[^a-zA-Zа-яА-Я]*", data)  так  не сработает? у меня возвращает ['whatever', 'wherever', 'solution', 'solut', 'onal']

Comment: @Андр поправил, ну там смысл в том, что по заданию слова могут быть разделены не только пробелами но и любыми символами, и если какого то символа не хватает в качестве разделителя просто в регулярку через `|` можно добавить

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч не хватало запятой в регулярке вашей)))

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч Но не проходит 9 тест(ошибку прикрепил в вопрос) у вас при 9 тесте ничего не выводит вообще

Comment: @Андр входные данные дайте для 9 теста

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч после update смотрите, там ниже строки _ввод_

Comment: @Андр Поправил, вы бы сразу все нужные условия в вопросе писали )

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч так я и сам их узнаю по мере выполнения программы, вначале дают только 2 теста)) а если ошибка , то показывают в каком именно

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч теперь 1 тест не проходит((

Comment: @Андр Поправил, под все ваши описанные в вопросе тесты, т.е. с теми водными данными которые вы указали в вопросе все тесты проходят успешно

Comment: @ИгорьИгоряныч да, теперь все работает верно

Comment: @Андр Исправил еще раз, там ошибка была, точнее куча лишнего кода из за ошибки, сейчас все хорошо

Comment: @Андр еще короче сделал